# Consider a $5 \times 5$ invertible matrix with entries from $0,1$. What is the minimum difference between the number of $1$'s and $0$'s?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a $5\times5$ invertible matrix with entries from $0,1$. What is the minimum difference between number of $1$'s and $0$'s?

Answer:

> $1$

I have proceeded as follows. I have found $4$ linearly independent row vectors

$$(1,0,1,0,1),(0,1,0,1,0),(1,1,1,0,0),(1,0,0,0,1)$$

but I couldn't find the 5th one to construct the invertible matrix with minimum difference between number of $1$'s and $0$'s. How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, you just need to play around till you find 5 linearly independent row vectors that contain 12 or 13 1's amongst them.

---

As a slight hint for such a set:

> In the set that I found, I used $(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$ and 4 other vectors that each had 2 1's in them.

Comment: That's a good idea

Answer (score 1):

My try: for a $4\times4$ matrix we can get difference zero:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now for $5\times5$ we extend the procedure:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Easily extended for any $n\times n$-matrix.

Answer (score 0):

With those four vectors, the fifth vector $(1,0,1,0,0)$ will complete your set and give you five linearly independent vectors. I found it by trial and error by entering the rows into a matrix on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det%7B%7B1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C+0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%7D) and checking whether the resulting determinant is non-zero (this was the second vector I tried).